# Can I specify an object with @SerializedName in its params as a @Field in a url-encoded POST request?

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit

Take the following JSON i want to send to an API:

```
{
    "param1": "1",
    "param2": "2",
    "param3": {
        "param3-1": "3-1",
        "param3-2": "3-2"
    }
}
```

And my object for param3 is:

```
data class param3Object(
    @SerializedName("param3-1") param3_1: String,
    @SerializedName("param3-2") param3_2: String
)
```

Is it possible to pass the above object into an API request @Field attribute:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/something")
fun doSomething(
    @Field("param1") param1: String, 
    @Field("param2") param2: String,
    @Field("param3") param3: param3Object
): Call<MyResponse>
```

so that it represents the JSON at the top of this post? Or do I need to individually pass parameters as @Field? I'm trying to think of ways not to waste time boilerplating.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use it as `REQUEST BODY`

```
@POST("api/something")
fun createUser(@Body data: Data) : Call<MyResponse>
```

and define model

```
data class Data(
    @SerializedName("param1") val param1: String,
    @SerializedName("param2") val param2: String,
    @SerializedName("param3") val param3: SubData
)

data class SubData(
    @SerializedName("param3-1") val param3_1: String,
    @SerializedName("param3-2") val param3_2: String
)
```

EDIT

If you really want send this as formUrlEncoded, then probably simple solution is to change parameter3 to string, and serialize data before put it to method, or even better change everything to single parameter and serialize whole object

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering as I've tried @Body tags before and got Multipart encoding errors. I actually had this written out but didn't test it, got sceptical and replaced it lol.

Comment: so just try to remove `@FormUrlEncoded` and do it in REST way by sending data as json body. Or if you really want to do this as `@FormUrlEncoded` could you past error which you received?

Comment: To be honest in my opinion it's not the best idea to send json as formUrlEncoded, generally lot of examples show usage only with primitives - strings, number, booleans

Comment: I updated my response with deleting formurlencoded and gave some way to do this with this annotation